# Rename sequences in fasta file

Tags: awk, rename, fasta

I am new to this so sorry in advance for the question.

I have a FASTA file and would like to rename my sequence name. The initial record looks like this:

```
>TV-B-PCR1_S14_M02625_124_000000000-B85HY_1_1101_14139_4234
CCTA...
```

and I want to convert it to something like this:

```
>TV-B-PCR1_1101-14139-4234
CCTA...
```

Thank you so much in advance any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your problem is easy to solve. But have you tried first google some very basic usage of text processing tool like awk,sed.....? Next time when you have other problem, you just come again, asking and taking?

Comment: sorry, but this forum doesn't provide free coding service.. please click [edit] and add code you've tried.. also, please explain the logic behind the transformation.. if you need learning resources, see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info

Comment: also, you could shorten the sample input shown here considerably by reducing characters starting from `CCTA....`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: are you also a user of this `bioawk` tool?